# Tkinter возвращает исключение AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Tags: python

Всем привет! Помогите разобраться почему возвращает исключение.

```
import tkinter as tk

FONT = ('Courier', 30)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Считалочка')
root.geometry('500x400+400+300')

number = tk.Label(root, text=int(0), font=FONT). grid(row=0, column=0)

btn_plus = tk.Button(root, text='+', font=FONT, width=10)
btn_plus.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=20)

def click_plus():
    a = 0
    result = a + 1
    number.config(text=result)

btn_plus.config(command=click_plus)

root.mainloop()
```

Не могу понять почему он ругается на конфиг.

Comment: Здравствуйте на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, см. [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что в команде

```
number = tk.Label(root, text=int(0), font=FONT). grid(row=0, column=0)
```

метод `.grid()` возвращает `None`, значит, в переменной `number` будет `None`, а не вами созданный объект типа `Label`.

Потому ваше `number.config(text=result)` является попыткой применить метод `.config()` на объект `None`, т.е. на объект типа `NoneType`, как сообщает ваша ошибка.

Разделите вашу команду на две:

```
number = tk.Label(root, text=int(0), font=FONT)
number.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

---

Между прочим, у вас логическая ошибка в функции `click_plus()` - в переменной `result` будет всегда `1`, потому что в переменной `a` есть всегда нуль.

Исправите её так, что вместо

```
а = 0
```

присоедините переменной `a` *текущее значение:*

```
a = number['text']
```